# Is there a way to get minimal Wordpress functions for iframed content?

Tags: headers

I have a bit of content in a PHP file that is designed to live inside an iframe on another page. The PHP file is very simple-- here it is in its entirety right now:

```
<div class="content-tos">
    <?php
        // get the terms of service from other page
        $getpage = get_page_by_path('/terms-of-service');
        echo apply_filters('the_content', $getpage->post_content);
    ?>
</div>
```

Obviously I need to include something above these lines of code so the PHP has access to the Wordpress core functions (like `get_page_by_path()`)... but if I use `get_header()` I get my entire header, nav bar, Google Analytics tracking code etc, which then appear inside the iframe, which I definitely don't want.

Is there a way in Wordpress to do some kind of include that will give me the basic Wordpress API but won't draw a full HTML header, etc, etc, etc from the `header.php` file?

Comment: *so the PHP has access to the Wordpress core functions*. I don't understand, what do you need to get from the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want `get_header`, then don't call `get_header()`. It's a simple as that, the `get_header` function is not where all of the WP core is initialized. The simplest way to do this is using the template hierarchy to create a template for a specific page slug or id.

From the WP Admin, create a page at the URL you want to use.

```
http://example.com/tos
```

Then create a template file that [follows the rules for overriding the template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for that specific page.

```
wp-content/themes/<your-theme>/page-tos.php
```

From there you can put whatever you want in `page-tos.php` and have full access to WP functions and API. And you can disable it by simply unpublishing the page from the WP Admin as well.

Answer (score 0):

Think perhaps you're confusing `get_header()` with the file `wp-blog-header.php`. The first is a theming function generally used to pull stuff into the `<head>` section of your HTML. The file `wp-blog-header.php` essentially bootstraps WordPress.

Try this:

```
<div class="content-tos">
    <?php
        require('/path/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
        // get the terms of service from other page
        $getpage = get_page_by_path('/terms-of-service');
        echo apply_filters('the_content', $getpage->post_content);
    ?>
</div>
```